# how to check file format in server side

Tags: php, jquery

```
var $imagefile = $('<input />')
    .attr({
        type: 'file',
        name: 'imageFile',
        id: 'imageFile'
    });
```

Above is my code which creates a file input.

Below is the code which checks if a file format is correct in a table row:

```
function validation() {

    var marks = parseInt($("#total-weight").text());    
    var _qid = "";
    var _msg = "";


    var allowedTypes = ["jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png"];

    var path = $("#imageFile").val();
    var ext = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();


    var alertValidation = "";
    // Note, this is just so it's declared...
    $("tr.optionAndAnswer").each(function() {


        _qid = $("td.qid",this).text();
        _msg = "You have errors on Question Number: " + _qid + "\n";


         $("#imageFile",this).each(function() {

        if ($.inArray(ext, allowedTypes) < 0) {
        alertValidation += '\n\u2022 Unsupported file type';
        }

         if (alertValidation != "") {
                return false; //Stop the each loop 
            }

    });

        if(alertValidation != ""){
            return false;
        }
    });


    if (alertValidation != "") {
        alert(_msg + alertValidation);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Now this checks for the file formats in client side, but how can I also check it in server side using php?

Comment: What do you mean by 'check it in server side'? What do you want to do?

Comment: I have been told that I chould not only check file format in client side but check it in server side, I really don't know what it means but they said if you don't check it server side then it creates security issues. I believe I need to check it on server side using php coding

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

```
<?php
$allowedImageTypes = array("image/pjpeg","image/jpeg","image/jpg","image/png","image/x-png","image/gif");
$file = $_FILES['imageFile'];
$fileType = $file['type'];
if (!in_array($fileType, $allowedImageTypes)) { 
    echo "Unsupported file type";
}
else
{
    // Process the file
}
?>
```

**EDIT**

Since the user asked about the way to check server files as well. He can use this kind of way to check that.

```
<?php

$filePath = "image/image.jpg";
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($filePath);
$fileType = image_type_to_mime_type($type);
$allowedImageTypes = array("image/pjpeg","image/jpeg","image/jpg","image/png","image/x-png","image/gif");
if (!in_array($fileType, $allowedImageTypes)) { 
    echo "Unsupported file type";
}
else
{
    // Process the file
}

?>
```

Comment: does this code also go into the javascript <script> tag or outside the script tag?

Comment: it is giving me this error when i put the code in: 
Notice: Undefined index: imageFile in /web/stud/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable.php on line 656

Comment: Also I want it to check the files on server side after the user has clicked on the submit button, so do I place this code after the myClickhandler() function which controls the submit button?

Comment: This script is written to verify uploading images. Give me couple of minutes to suggest you a way to check the type of files in the server.

Comment: @user1182476. I modified my answer. Please check.

Comment: Can I ask what does the $filePath actually do?

Comment: $filePath has the path to the file.

Comment: Ok what my question is that when I open up page it already states unsupported file. What I want is that the user will select a file, click on the submit button and then display message if file is supported or not. I will create a testpage to show you, give me another 5 mins

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7444/discussion-between-prasad-rajapaksha-and-user1182476)

Comment: Ok this is the [link](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Files/Files.php) to the application. Open the app and you will see the message. Click on the "Add Question" buttonand you will see the file input tag. Now what I want is that if you select a valid file, then remove the message else if there is a invalid file, then show message. Add multiple row and add multiple file formats for you to test.

Answer (score 0):

Once the file is uploaded, you can just take a look at `$_FILES['imageFile']['type']` to get the mime type.

Comment: Where do I put this in my code, is it just a seperate php tag and put the code in or does this code need to be put in a javascript function in between php tags?

Comment: You can put this anywhere you want in your php code.  PHP has nothing to do with javascript in any way whatsoever, so never ask that again.

Answer (score 0):

I would use PHP's finfo_file function:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

Example from php page:

```
<?php
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
foreach (glob("*") as $filename) {
    echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename) . "\n";
}
finfo_close($finfo);
```

Outputs:

text/html
image/gif
application/vnd.ms-excel

Comment: Is there a way I can use this code to check the file on server side but do not show the information on the file or wether its valid or not, I want to use an alert to state if file is valid or not? I have already set up the alert.